# ContentMD5Missing - Amazon Webservice

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to post to Feed -> SubmitFeed.

However the exception I receive back is:

> you must pass a Content-MD5 HTTP header for your feed so we can be
>   sure it was not corrupted (e.g. dropped a 0 from a price) before we
>   process it

What I don't understand is the documentation states that it is optional so unsure why I am receiving this. Plus I am actually passing something through.

XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" schemaLocation="amzn-base.xsd">
- <Header>
  <DocumentVersion>1</DocumentVersion> 
  <MerchantIdentifier>A1ddWU5JfffWJEddV9Xf668B</MerchantIdentifier> 
  </Header>
  <MessageType>Product</MessageType> 
  <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace> 
- <Message>
  <MessageId>1</MessageId> 
  <OperationType>Update</OperationType> 
  </Message>
- <Product>
  <SKU>3308ff6-01</SKU> 
  </Product>
  </AmazonEnvelope>
```

How I attach the Body/Header

```
    var request = Helper.CreateWebRequest(xmlRequest.Config, genericparameters, signatureHelpers);

    request.Headers.Add("x-amazon-user-agent", amazonHostAgent);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = amazonConfig.ContentType;
    request.Timeout = 50000;

    Helper.AddXmlDocumentToRequest(xmlRequest.XmlDocument.InnerXml, request);

    public static void AddXmlDocumentToRequest(string xmlDocument, WebRequest request)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlDocument);
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        request.Headers.Add("Content-MD5", GetMd5HashFromStream(bytes));

        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
    }

    public static string GetMd5HashFromStream(byte[] bytes)
    {
        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            var hash = md5.ComputeHash(bytes);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        }
    }
```

Within the request when I drill down to Headers I have the following:

```
{x-amazon-user-agent: MWSApplication/1.0 (Language=c#)
Content-Type: text/xml
Host: mws.amazonservices.co.uk
Content-Length: 478
Expect: 100-continue
Content-MD5: 1xLxj5Y+WVsAVR9BbQfzQA==

}
```

When I run the xml through scratchpad it returns the same `Content-MD5: 1xLxj5Y+WVsAVR9BbQfzQA==`

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,

Clare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the answer for everyone however it was for me and if it helps one other person I will be happy :-)

Me being very stupid, added the header after the streaming, this is not what you should be doing.

1. Create the URL
2. Add headers and other elements i.e.
   request.ContentType
3. Stream documents (body of request) if required
4. request.GetResponse.

Thanks,

Clare